# Turn off Disabled in the entire row in table when is button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm studying how to make a dynamic edit button without all these repeated codes and just changing the selector. I'm thinking, is there a way with one edit class to turn off the disabled in the entire row where the edit button is placed? JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/Lv1a39rk/15/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
              integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('table tr td input').prop('disabled', true);
});
</script>
<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Settings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TestData</td>
    <td><input = "text"></td>
    <td><input = "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TestData</td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TestData</td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TestData</td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TestData</td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TestData</td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

and the one I come up with is this, but I'm just repeating the code and just changing the selector, is there an easy way and lesser code? JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/Lv1a39rk/18/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
              integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Settings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>testdata</td>
    <td><input = "text"></td>
    <td><input = "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit_1">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>testdata</td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit_2">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>testdata</td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit_3">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>testdata</td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit_4">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>testdata</td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit_5">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>testdata</td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit_6">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('table tr td input').prop('disabled', true);
    $( "td:eq( 2 )" ).css( "color", "red" );

    $('#edit_1'). click(function (){
        $("tr:nth-child(2) td:eq(1) input").prop( "disabled", false );
        $("tr:nth-child(2) td:eq(2) input").prop( "disabled", false );
    });

    $('#edit_2').click(function (){
        $("tr:nth-child(3) td:eq(1) input").prop( "disabled", false );
        $("tr:nth-child(3) td:eq(2) input").prop( "disabled", false );
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML in your first example is invalid.  An ID attribute must be unique throughout the entire page per the HTML specification, your second example is better.  When you find yourself doing this, use class attributes instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('button').click(function (){
        $(this).parents('tr').find('input').prop( "disabled", false );
});
```

Comment: Better to use `closest('tr')` instead of `parents('tr')` in case of nested tables.

Answer (score 2):

do like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
     integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Settings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>testdata</td>
    <td><input = "text"></td>
    <td><input = "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit_1">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>testdata</td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit_2">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>testdata</td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit_3">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>testdata</td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit_4">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>testdata</td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit_5">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>testdata</td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit_6">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('table tr td input').prop('disabled', true);
    $( "td:eq( 2 )" ).css( "color", "red" );

    $('button'). click(function (){
        $(this).closest("tr").find("input").prop('disabled', false);
    });
    
    
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

All your buttons basically do the same thing so you do not want to access all of them separately. You might want to make it like so:

```
<tr id="row-1">
  <td>testdata</td>
  <td><input type= "text"></td>
  <td><input type= "text"></td>
  <td><button class="edit-button" data-row-id="row-1">Edit</button></td>
</tr>
```

If you do that is is sufficient to have your JavaScipt event look like this:

```
$(".edit-button").click(function () {
  $("#" + $(this).data("row-id") + " input").prop( "disabled", false );
});
```

Don't want to change your JS? Do as other answers suggested:

```
$('button').click(function (){
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input').prop( "disabled", false );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your HTML is you have given same ID to all buttons while ID should be unique through out the HTML page. But then too you can use below code in script tag to get desired output-

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('table tr td input').prop('disabled', true);
    $('button').click(function(e){
        $(this).parents('tr').find('input').prop('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

Detailed code snippet is like below-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
 integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
 crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('table tr td input').prop('disabled', true);
    $('button').click(function(e){
  $(this).parents('tr').find('input').prop('disabled', false);
 });
});
</script>
<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Settings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TestData</td>
    <td><input = "text"></td>
    <td><input = "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TestData</td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TestData</td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TestData</td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TestData</td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TestData</td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><input type= "text"></td>
    <td><button id = "edit">Edit</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own. Try the below code

```js
var data = [
  {
    company: 'One',
    contact: 'Yes',
    country: 'India'
  }, {
    company: 'Two',
    contact: 'No',
    country: 'US'
  }, {
    company: 'Three',
    contact: 'Yes',
    country: 'UK'
  }
]
$(document).ready(function(){
  appendDataToTable();
  $('#table-container tbody').on('click', 'button', function() {
    editClickBtn($(this));
  })
})

function appendDataToTable() {
  data.map(function(eachData) {
    var row = '<tr class="disabled">'
    row += '<td>'+eachData.company+'</td>'
    row += '<td><input type="text" disabled /></td>'
    row += '<td><input type="text" disabled /></td>'
    row += '<td><button>Edit</button></td>'
    row += '</tr>';
    $('#table-container tbody').append(row);
  })
}

function editClickBtn(that) {
  $(that).closest('tr').removeClass('disabled');
  $(that).closest('tr').find('input').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
td, th {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='table-container'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Company</td>
      <td>Contact</td>
      <td>Country</td>
      <td>Country</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: No need to create all those elements with java script.

Comment: When you consider modular programming, data are provided as an array of object. Consider any modern frameworks, if the data is dynamic, then there is no other way that adding it like this. Also, this approach minimizes the use of HTML code with simple JS codes which helps to render much faster.

Comment: plenty of "modern" frameworks have some kind of template with data bindings mechanism, however some situations may require you to add html like that yes. However that is not the case for the question of the OP and therefore irrelevant for this situation since there are way better solutions.

Comment: Yes, If that's meant to be like that. then go for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can both enable and disable, for this, I added a "save" button to disable again once edit is done and showed how to do that.

Use classes for the button and hook that event handler to the table to avoid issues such as a form submit button or other buttons on your page.

Note: you could also find all the OTHER Edit buttons and disable those when you are editing one row.  To do that you would add this to the click handlers

```
let editbutton = row.find('.edit'); // not this row
$('#myedittable').find('.edit').not(editbutton).prop('disabled', true);
```

and in save

```
$('#myedittable').find('.edit').prop('disabled', false);
```

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myedittable').find('input[type="text"]').add('.save').prop('disabled', true);
});
$('#myedittable').on('click', '.edit', function() {
  let row = $(this).closest('tr');
  let savebutton = row.find('.save');
  row.find('input[type=text]').add(savebutton).prop('disabled', false);
});
$('#myedittable').on('click', '.save', function() {
  let row = $(this).closest('tr');
  let savebutton = row.find('.save');
  row.find('input[type="text"]').add(savebutton).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<h2>HTML Table</h2>
<table id="myedittable">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Settings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TestData</td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><button class="edit">Edit</button></td>
    <td><button class="save">Save</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TestData</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><button class="edit">Edit</button></td>
    <td><button class="save">Save</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TestData</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><button class="edit">Edit</button></td>
    <td><button class="save">Save</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TestData</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><button class="edit">Edit</button></td>
    <td><button class="save">Save</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TestData</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><button class="edit">Edit</button></td>
    <td><button class="save">Save</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TestData</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><button class="edit">Edit</button></td>
    <td><button class="save">Save</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```